# get distinguish element of an array of object by lodash/underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have input is an array of object like this:

```
var input = [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "price": 100
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "price": 3000
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "price": 200
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "price": 200
            }

        ]
```

I wanna distinguish the element to get the output like:

```
var output = [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "price": 100
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "price": 3000
            },
            {
                "id": "4_8",
                "price": 200
            }

        ]
```

by lodash.
I really need your help, thank you so much

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In Lodash, you can use [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) followed by [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map):

```js
var input = [{"id":1,"price":100},
             {"id":2,"price":3000},
             {"id":4,"price":200},
             {"id":8,"price":200}];

var output = _(input)
  .groupBy('price')
  .map((vs, k) => ({
      id: _.map(vs, 'id').join('_'),
      price: +k
  }))
  .value();
    
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: could you please help me in a solution of reverse from output to input ? @4castle, thank you so much

Comment: @Blueskyy You can use `_.split` on the `id` field inside of the callback of `_.flatMap` to do the reverse operation. (Note: this isn't a code writing site. Questions need to show effort and a specific problem with the attempt)